# SQL query for printing n rows

Tags: sql

I need a query which prints rows by the n number represented against it. example

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect for this sample data.

Comment: I just needed generic answer I was aware of the recursive query answer but was wondering if it could be done in some other way.

Comment: I have not tagged any DBMS to keep it open for all you can use MySQL, PostgreSQL or oracle or anything that you're comfortable with

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified your DBMS, the following solution will work for PostgreSQL:

```
select t.nr
from generate_series(1,4) as t(nr)
  cross join generate_series(1,t.nr)
order by t.nr;
```

With 100% standard ANSI SQL, you can do this:

```
with recursive numbers (nr) as (
  select * from (values (1) ) as t
  union all
  select p.nr + 1
  from numbers p
  where p.nr + 1 <= 4
)
select t.*
from numbers t
  join numbers t2 on t2.nr <= t.nr
order by t.nr;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server

```
declare @n int  = 5; // your n value 
declare @i int = 1; 
declare @j int = 1; 
declare @tmp table (val int)

WHILE (@i <= @n) 
BEGIN   
       WHILE (@j <= @i)     
       BEGIN        
            insert into @tmp(val) values(@i)
            set @j = @j + 1;    
       END  
set @j = 1;
set @i = @i + 1; 
END 
select * from @tmp
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  ,jarlh,  it's ok (y)